# Zoom to specific longtitude and latitude ArcGis android sdk

Tags: android, arcgis

i have `arcgis` map and i want to zoom to specific point when the layer is loaded 
here is my code

```
  tileLayer.setOnStatusChangedListener(new OnStatusChangedListener() {
        public void onStatusChanged(Object source, STATUS status) {
            if (OnStatusChangedListener.STATUS.INITIALIZED == status) {
                map.addLayer(tileLayer);
                map.centerAndZoom(54.352792, 24.479618, 16);});
```

but it doesn't works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed my problem by adding the change listener on the map not on the layer

```
map.setOnStatusChangedListener(new OnStatusChangedListener() {
        public void onStatusChanged(Object source, STATUS status) {
            if (OnStatusChangedListener.STATUS.INITIALIZED == status) {
                map.addLayer(tileLayer);
                map.centerAndZoom(54.352792, 24.479618, 16);});
```

Comment: can you please help me here ? 

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44472797/arcgis-10-2-9-offline-editing-the-attribute`